# Call function saved as string on chosen object

Tags: javascript, function, call

I have something like:

```
var sFunction = 'my_function("param1", "param2")';
var oMyObject = ...;
```

And I want to combine it so the result would be equal to:

```
oMyObject.my_function("param1", "param2");
```

Would much appreciate any tips.

---

Remark

As many of you suggested to find a root cause and try not to deal with the problematic input here are some pieces of information about the origins of the "problem". 
The `sFunction` comes from database, hardcoded in one of the columns. It is custom one which should be called on object retrieved basing on other parameters of `sFunction`'s database record. 
So being backed up by your comments I will try suggesting changing data model in hope that it is not too late for that. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: It might be easier to solve the problem you initially had, where does the sFunction string come from, and why is it a String? This might be a case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Does `oMyObject` have a `my_function` method? And why the weird mix of snake and camel case?

Comment: So, you want to turn a string into code. That is generally inadvisable for security and performance reasons, but it is doable with `eval()`. The bigger question is, what ultimately are you trying to accomplish as there is almost always a better approach than this.

Comment: I am given that as an input, it may come from db or anywhere else. I just have to deal with it in described way.

Comment: *"I am given that as an input, it may come from db or anywhere else. I just have to deal with it in described way"*...yep, definitely a very appropriate situation for doing a nice and harmless `eval`...

Comment: @michelson `eval('oMyObject.' + sFunction);`. Note that if you did that in production code and I were your boss I'd (depending on your past performance) give you an official reprimand or fire you.

Comment: Remember, `Eval is Evil`

Comment: Yeeee, I was hoping that you guys would come up with not-`eval` solution. @JaredSmith I'll talk to my boss first :D

Answer (score 1):

> I am given that as an input, it may come from db or anywhere else. I just have to deal with it in described way.

As [Luca noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922161/call-function-saved-as-string-on-chosen-object#comment86860006_49922161), you're probably best off solving the problem that brought you to the point of having code in a string that you feel you need to evaluate at runtime. The number of use cases for doing that is very low.

For instance, instead of

```
sFunction = 'my_function("param1", "param2")';
```

perhaps you could have

```
call = {
    f: "my_function",
    params: ["param1", "param2"]
};
```

Then it's:

```
oMyObject[call.f].apply(oMyObject, call.params);
```

`call` could even start life as JSON text you parse -- live example:

```js
var json =
  '{' +
      '"f": "my_function",' +
      '"params": ["param1", "param2"]' +
  '}';
var call = JSON.parse(json);
var oMyObject = {
    my_function: function(p1, p2) {
        console.log(p1, p2);
    }
};

oMyObject[call.f].apply(oMyObject, call.params);
```

That's *markedly* safer than an arbitrary code execution.

You *can* do this with your `sFunction` (`eval("oMyObject." + sFunction)`), but consider:

- It lets any arbitrary code in `sFunction` run.
- If User A supplies the code and then you run it on User B's system, you're compromising User B's privacy. (*I am not a lawyer*, but you could be doing so in a way that violates a country's data protection or privacy laws.)

Now, if you're loading code from a DB and you know that the code in the DB can only be put there by trusted people (for instance, developers on your team, **not** end users of the system), that's fine, it's largely like running a script file. But there's almost certainly a better way to do it than delivering the code as a string and `eval`ing it.

But if the code comes from "anywhere else", it's **not** fine; see bullet points above. The setup is fundamentally broken and better options are available. Take that information to your boss, and if necessary to his/her boss, and if necessary his/her boss, until you find someone who can change the requirement.

Comment: *(If you see `call.f.apply(oMyObject, call.params);` above, hit refresh. Oops.)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a string hack that doesn't use `eval()`, but as I (and others) have said, this is not a good solution. The better solution would be to return the function name and any arguments as a comma delimited string, which would at least make this kind of solution more straight-forward.

```js
var sFunction = 'my_function("param1", "param2")';

// The object would have to already have the function:
var oMyObject = {
  my_function: function(x,y){
    return x + y;
  }
};

// Remove the last ")" and split the remainder into an array at the "("
var funcParts = sFunction.replace(")","").split("(");

// Split the second part (the arguments) into its own array
var funcArgs = funcParts[1].split(",");

// Pass the function name as a string key to the object and then pass the arguments to that
console.log(oMyObject[funcParts[0]](funcArgs[0], funcArgs[1]));
```

The bigger question is, what ultimately are you trying to accomplish as there is almost always a better approach than this.

Answer (score 0):

To do a dynamic function call you can of course eval as I did in the comments, which is of course a terrible idea. Here is a quick-and-dirty alternative:

```
const dynamicCallMethod = (obj, s) => {
  try {
    const fname = s.match(/([$\w]+\(/);
    const params = s.match(/("[\w$]+")/g);
    return obj[fname](...params);
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
};
```

Note I still think there's any easier way to do this if you describe the scenario in more detail. The above will fail for any non-ascii characters, for instance.